# Why does an int number in do (while number > 10) gives an endless loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, initialization, int

In my understandings, the while should end the loop, cause
int number "in" the loop should initialize it with 0.
Or am i wrong? But it gives me an endless loop, printing zeroes.
I compiled it with gcc and tried to debug it with gdb.
It makes no sense for me, that the while doesn't stop the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 20;
    do
    {
        int number = number / 2;
        printf("%d ", number);
    } while (number > 10);
}
```

Comment: because you never change `number` from the function scope. You created a new variable with the same name in the loop scope ==> remove the `int` in `int number = number / 2;`.

Comment: yeah, i know, when i remove int .. then it works, but i want to know, .. why "while" doest not break the loop.. when it's newly initialized all the time.. it should be zero.. and so while should break... or am i wrong?

Comment: this could help you understand https://godbolt.org/g/UL9Wd3

Comment: "when it's newly initialized all the time .. it should be zero."  It is never initialized to zero. You initialize to 20 and never change it.

Comment: `int number = number / 2;` invokes undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: You seem to be missing some of the most basic warnings - are you compiling without enabling them, or did the messages not help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create new `number` every time in the loop, visible only within the loop and unrelated to the one outside the loop. Remove `int` in `int number = number / 2;`

Comment: so the while uses the "outer" number?.. and the inner number is never seen by the while? .. so while only sees (number(which is 20) > 10 is TRUE)? ... but now i see the scope problem.. thanks!

Comment: Well, inner number lives only as long as the code inside the brackets is executed. So when it reaches while (number > 10); it doesn't even exist anymore.